# mysql JDBC connector load balancing options

Tags: mysql, jdbc

The connection URL for mysql can have three schema forms when running a clustered database environment:

```
jdbc:mysql://node1,node2

jdbc:mysql:loadbalance//node1,node2

jdbc:mysql:replication//node1,node2
```

Unfortunately the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-multi-host-connections.html) doesn't really explain the differences. It appears anecdotally that 'loadbalance' will send each request to a different random node and the first form with no special scheme will send all requests to the first node until it fails. But there is nothing I can find about the 'replication' scheme.

Further, loadbalance would imply "failoverReadOnly=false" but that needs to be provided explicitly for the first form with no special scheme.

Where does 'replication' fit into all this?

Answer (score -1):

It's a new 8.0 feature it seems:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html

Comment: Nothing there that says anything of the sort. Both feature were present in 5.1.